# Ugly thick style border when Form.toplevel = false

Tags: c#, forms

I have a form that will display a number of gauges that the user can resize, move around close, etc. For this I use:

```
Form gaugeForm = new GaugeForm();
gaugeForm.TopLevel = false;
gaugeForm.Parent = this;
gaugeForm.Show();
```

The problem is that the gaugeForm has a thick, ugly, old-style border. If I open the same form without modifying parent/toplevel, it looks like all the other forms, but I want it to be inside the main form.

Any pointers? This is how it looks: [Ugly form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmyeH.jpg)

Cheers,
Jostein

Comment: You could try setting it to be borderless, e.g. `gaugeForm.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;`. Here is a helpful link with an alternative: [Remove Windows Form Titlebar In C#](http://www.vcskicks.com/remove-titlebar.php)

Comment: The Windows 10 visual styles renderer is a bit of a hack job.  Microsoft has basically given up on keeping it compatible across Windows versions.  Pretty evident when you look at the form in the designer, it doesn't have the Win10 style either.  There is no known way to get the Win10 frame style renderer, you always get the Win7 compatibility style.  Pretty important to change the FormBorderStyle when you turn a toplevel window into a control.  Not just for the looks, also important to stop the user from moving it around, child controls should not be movable.